# Tracing in disconnected Systems

Tags: cadence-workflow, distributed-tracing, data-tracing

I know there are libraries for tracing requests in distributed systems based on OpenTracing and OpenTelemetry; these all work because the requests are connected/chained(microservices talking to each other). How to trace when systems/services are disconnected?

Service X calls Service Y. Y performs some processing then writes to a shared location . A component Z polls shared location(after hrs) and does processing.

I want to know if for each of the request generated by X, the status at each of these 3 systems.

A simple way to track this would be have a table and update DB Entries.
However considering the fact that I might need to retry certain things, I had thought of introducing a workflow engine(Cadence) that opens up a workflow at Service X. Then at each of the Services the workflow is updated. If Request Reaches Y, a step in w/f is completed. If it does not reach Z the workflow is left open and after some time I could generate an Email etc. saying the workflow failed.

I need help in understanding if this is the right way and/or different methods to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most typical use cases of Cadence Workflow. The recommended solution is   let service X to start a workflow. It will execute an activity to make a service call to service Y. If possible, let Component Z to send a [signal](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/java-client/signals/) to the workflow, telling that the processing is done. Or you can have another activity to keep polling the status.

Note that back off [retry](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/java-client/retries/#retryoptions) can be done easily for activities supported by Cadence.

Then use a timer in the workflow to trigger an activity to send email.

Finally the status of this workflow is still as a local variable of the workflow. You can implement a [Query](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/java-client/queries/) handler in the workflow to get status. Or you can implement a background activity to report the progress proactively .

Open tracing library framework is for solving another problem. It is to measuring and analyzing service dependency and latency. In fact, Cadence workflow also supports open tracing here is the [example](https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/tree/master/cmd/samples/recipes/ctxpropagation). It is for service level, not for a particular requests or processing.

Comment: I forgot to mention explicitly but I need to get an overall latency as well; like for example when the Request is initiated at X how long it takes to Reach to Z. Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of ways doing it.

Within a workflow You can get the current timestamp of any step using Workflow.Now() API. 

If Z is a separate component that need to send a signal back, let it send a object with a time stamp in it. So that you can use time stamp to calculate how long it takes to reach Z. Or In Z query the start time and do the calculations.  If Z is also an activity of the workflow, you can also use the open tracing framework

Comment: Cadence also emit a lot of standard metric like workflow and activity latency. You can get them for free